# Why doesn't JW Player work in a custom content type?

Tags: nodes

I downloaded *JW Player* and used it on the default *Page* content type that comes with Drupal to show videos; it worked seamlessly.

I created a content type with a video field and I attaching videos normally in both the fields, but when I use the content type I created, it doesn't show a video. It shows a blunt listing of the *Video Link*.

How can I make *JW player* show videos in the content type I created?

The following is the markup shown for the content types.

#### Page

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="field-item even">
    <div class="jwplayer-video"> 
      <div id="a7638d2f8c40bfe2669593f3ee69e066_wrapper" style="position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://player.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" id="a76593f3ee69e066" name="a76593f3ee69e066" tabindex="0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="flashvars" value="netstreambasepath=page24_2.mp4&amp;skin=glow.xml&amp;autostart=1&amp;controlbar.position=none">
        </object>
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

#### Content type I created

```html
<div class="field-items">
  <div class="field-item even">
    <span class="file">
      <img class="file-icon" alt="" title="video/mp4" src="/0065bd-doc/ops-lop/modules/file/icons/video-x-generic.png"> 
      <a href="/page24_3.mp4" type="video/mp4; length=4838313">page24.mp4</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You checked the display settings of your new content type, did you?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this

1. [Jwplayer Drupal Module](https://drupal.org/project/jw_player)

Video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAAIfi0pYHw

2. Embedding jwplayer in HTML5

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player/

For your example :

WRONG CODE (dont use)

```
<div class="field-item even">

<span class="file">

<img class="file-icon" alt="" title="video/mp4" src="/0065bd-doc/ops-lop/modules/file/icons/video-x-generic.png"> 

<a href="/page24_3.mp4" type="video/mp4; length=4838313">page24.mp4</a>

</span></div></div>
```

Try This

```
<div class="field-items">

    <div class="field-item even">
        <span class="file">

            <img class="file-icon" alt="" title="video/mp4" src="/0065bd-doc/ops-lop/modules/file/icons/video-x-generic.png"> 

            <div id='playerNrEyADwjFyrz' onclick='jwVideoSetup('/page24_3.mp4')'></div>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function jwVideoSetup(src)
                {
                    jwplayer('playerNrEyADwjFyrz').setup({
                       file: src,
                       title: 'video title',
                       width: '100%',
                       aspectratio: '16:9'
                    });
                }
            </script>

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```